# How to pivot Latitude and Longitude data and assign a value to dintinguish Origin from Destination in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having a problem that I feel it has a simple solution, however I'm currently unable to reach the desired output. I have data related to some road segments, consisting of the Segment ID, Start Latitude and Longitude of the segment and End Latitude and Longitude of the segment, totalling 5 columns.

A replicative example of my data can be found below using dput()

```
Segment ID      Start Latitude  End Latitude  Start Longitude End Longitude
1 1001838306       41.15166     41.15504        -8.64235      -8.64522
2  306441634       41.11694     41.11841        -8.62556      -8.62489
3  409303476       41.11498     41.11484        -8.62581      -8.62554
```

```
dput(example)
structure(list(`Segment ID` = c(1001838306L, 306441634L, 409303476L
), `Start Latitude` = c(41.15166, 41.11694, 41.11498), `End Latitude` = c(41.15504, 
41.11841, 41.11484), `Start Longitude` = c(-8.64235, -8.62556, 
-8.62581), `End Longitude` = c(-8.64522, -8.62489, -8.62554)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I tried using 'gather' from dplyr to pivot data from 'Start Latitude' and 'End Latitude' into one column called 'Latitude' and repeat the process to a column called 'Longitude'.

```
example2 <- gather(example, key = "OD", value = "Latitude", c(2:3))
example3 <- gather(example2, key = "OD", value = "Longitude", c(2:3))
```

However this also requires me to create a 'key' column filled with

```
Segment ID    Latitude       OD        Longitude
1  1001838306 41.15166 Start Longitude  -8.64235
2   306441634 41.11694 Start Longitude  -8.62556
3   409303476 41.11498 Start Longitude  -8.62581
4  1001838306 41.15504 Start Longitude  -8.64235
5   306441634 41.11841 Start Longitude  -8.62556
6   409303476 41.11484 Start Longitude  -8.62581
7  1001838306 41.15166   End Longitude  -8.64522
8   306441634 41.11694   End Longitude  -8.62489
9   409303476 41.11498   End Longitude  -8.62554
10 1001838306 41.15504   End Longitude  -8.64522
11  306441634 41.11841   End Longitude  -8.62489
12  409303476 41.11484   End Longitude  -8.62554
```

My goal is for the column 'OD' to have the value "0" for "Start Latitude" and "Start Longitude". The value "1" would be assigned to "End Latitude" and "End Longitude".

I also feel that my approach is not elegant at all. Doing two consecutive 'gather' and then having to assign values to strings in a new column and then having to delete columns seems slow when bigger chunks of data require handling.

I would be thankful for any help or light shed my way.

Comment: Try `gather(example,k,val,-\`Segment ID\`) %>% separate(k,into = c('OD','k2'),sep='\\s+') %>% spread(k2,val)`, but I didn't get your last point, and you may not needed with the given solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take. But I confess that it is not very elegant...

```
library(tidyverse)

example %>% 
  unite("Start", contains("Start"), sep = ", ") %>% 
  unite("End" , contains("End"), sep = ", ") %>% 
  gather( key = "OD", value = "coordinates", c(2:3)) %>% 
  separate("coordinates", c("latitude", "Longitude"), sep = ", ") %>% 
  mutate(OD = ifelse(OD == "Start", 0, 1))
```